# In React-Native 0.68.0, what would make a difference between two computer configuration?

Tags: xcode, react-native

Here's the issue :

**My config :**

[image]

**A colleague config :**

[image]

Set up a brand new React-Native **0.68.0** project.

As you can see we almost have the same configuration. Only the processors are different.

My colleague can run it.

For my part, here's what I get from Xcode :
[image]

Why ?

I've re-started my computer, update pods, deleted Podfile.lock, re-installed pods ..etc.
I've tried to start new project with older version of React-Native, and it works fine.

**The issue occurs only with version >=0.68.0**

Comment: Which shell do you use? Can you try running `node -v` in your terminal, then in that terminal run `sh` and in that shell run `node -v` again.

Comment: ❯ node -v
v16.15.1
❯ sh
sh-3.2$ node -v
v16.15.1